# The usage of Mipfilter in effect file

Tags: xna, directx, shader, monogame

I've seen many people using the `MipFilter` in effect files. However, `MinFilter` and `MagFilter` are used for texture minifying and magnifying respectively, making `MipFilter`'s usage left unclear.

So I'm wondering that in what condition will `MipFilter`'s settings take effect.

Snipped code in Monogame `.fx` effect file below:

```
texture InputTexture;
sampler inputSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <InputTexture>;
    MipFilter = Point;  //What does this line mean?
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MipFilter is about interpolating between mipmaps levels while Min/MagFilter are about interpolating betwen pixels when sampling a mipmap level.

It can have two values :

- **POINT** sample the closest mipmap level (bilinear filtering)
- **LINEAR** linear interpolation between the two closest mip levels (trilinear filtering, better quality)

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/bb172615(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Do you mean that it will calculate between the mipmap levels such as 256x256 and 128x128?

Comment: Yes, when doing filtering the GPU needs to select a mipmap level depending on the distance of the pixel to the camera, the texture size and screen resolution. So let's say that there is a GPU "formula" which gives the mipmap level, this formula returns floating point values not integer, so it can return for example mipmaplevel=1.6, in this case, in POINT mode only the (closest) mip 2 will be sampled, in LINEAR mode mip1 and mip2 will be both sampled and final result will be 0.4*mip1 + 0.6*mip2, this gives a better result (but of course cost more)

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you for your detailed response.